# With 64-bit office 2013, "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded on 64-bit SQL server

Tags: ms-office, 32bit-64bit, sql-server-express, openrowset

I am using MS office 2013 64-bit (after uninstalling 32-bit office 2013) on a 64-bit computer (with windows 10), and SQL Server 2014 Express connected through IP address.

My goal is to let SQL Server read excel data, using "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET()" statement.

My problems is: I installed "AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe", but when executing "openrowset()", SQL Server gives me error msg "The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server." Please read the following so you'll know I did tons of research and trials.

The question is: should I use AccessDatabaseEngine or AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 in this case? And how?

Background - to make this question complicated:
When I had 32-bit office on my computer, and was using "import" function under "database" on SQL Server to import excel (.xlsx) data, SQL Server forced me to install AccessDatabaseEngine (the 32-bit). So I did. And the import became successful.
But I'd like to make SQL Server to read local excel files dynamically without importing, so I decided to set up excel as server using "New Linked Server" function in SQL Server, but failed. The error msg is basically "Cannot initialized the data source object of OLE DB Provider 'SQLNCLI11' for linked server "Mycomputer". Then I found "openrowset / opendatasource" statement, tried it on SQL Server, and got error msg: "The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server." The solutions I tried were the following:

1) uninstalled AccessDatabaseEngine;

2) instialled AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 (checked registry key to make sure its registered);

3) ran configurations as per "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2010/06/04/accessing-excel-files-on-a-x64-machine/";

4) ran "openrowset / opendatasource" again but still got msg "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server." Only now, I couldn't import excel (.xlsx) into SQL Server any longer, I guess because AccessDatabaseEngine was uninstalled;

5) uninstalled 32-bit office;

6) installed 64-bit office;

7 ) ran "openrowset / opendatasource" again, still got msg "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server."

8) uninstalled AccessDatabaseEngine_x64;

9) installed AccessDatabaseEngine, ran "openrowset / opendatasource" again, still got msg "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server."

The "Openrowset" statement I tries was like:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml;
   Database=C:\documents\2016.xlsx',
   [sheet1$]);
```

So it seems neither AccessDatabaseEngine nor AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 works for me for either 32-bit office or 64-bit office.

Did I miss something?

Thank you!

Comment: make sure you do not have Access 2007 connectivity component installed on the machine, if it was, reinstall access_2010_64